# C++ Cant accesss protected member variable without this pointer in template class

Tags: c++

Can someone please enlighten me on why this-> is required to access a parent class member variable in this scenario?

```
template <int S>
class A
{
protected:
    int x[S];
};

template <int S>
class B : public A<S>
{
    void Initialise()
    {
        this->x[0] = 0; // OK
        x[0] = 0;       // error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance...

EDIT:

This compiles OK:

```
template <int S>
class A
{
protected:
    int x[S];
};

class B : public A<5>
{
    void Initialise()
    {
        this->x[0] = 0; // OK
        x[0] = 0;       // OK
    }
};
```

Comment: fyi `B::x[0] = 0;` also works ... investigating.

Comment: Seeing the edit it looks like B isn't fully defined at the point where you try to access it (because B is a template), although it should (because we are in a function definition). Is there a language lawyer around that can clarify this?

Comment: @Timo - But if you move the definition B::Initialise out of line it still fails same error.

Comment: That's because `A<S>` is nothing until `S` is known, so you must qualify the name to ensure it's a member of parent class.

Comment: @davidbak that's what I'm saying. It looks like B isn't fully defined but it should be inside a function definition, no matter if inside or outside the class definition.

Comment: @Jack, correct because `A<S>::x[0] = 0` does work!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and the suggestion of the duplicate post.  And I searched so hard for an answer too and didn't find it.  Must have been googling it all wrong!

Comment: @Timo - ah, didn't know that "fully defined" didn't depend on seeing the "whole" decl in some way (thus that defining the method out-of-line wouldn't make a difference)

Comment: And in the second example, base class `A<5>` is not a dependent type, so its members can be seen for lookup.